# How can I call a method within a parent view from a child view in xamarin forms with paramaters

Tags: xamarin

I have tried to use Parent.Parent to be able to call the desired function within the parent view but I get the "Object not set to an instance" exception. Is there another method of doing this?

The following is the event to which the method within the parent view should be triggered.
[event within child view which should call function within parent view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpdwF.png)

This Parent.Parent will only get me to the "telerikDataControls:NonVirtualizedItemsControl"
and I require the Main parent view in order to call the function from the child view.
The following is elements that I used to display items within a list. This list is also within another list so this complicates things. This is unfortunately required for the data structure used for this data.

> ```
> <!--  Display items per Order  -->
>                                                         <telerikDataControls:NonVirtualizedItemsControl
>                                                             x:Name="lstChronicItems"
>                                                             Grid.Row="1"
>                                                             BackgroundColor="Transparent"
>                                                             ItemsSource="{Binding Chronics, Mode=TwoWay}"
>                                                             SelectionMode="None">
>                                                             <telerikDataControls:NonVirtualizedItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
>                                                                 <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:ChronicDataModel">
>                                                                     <telerikPrimitives:RadBorder>
>                                                                         <views:ChronicMainItemTemplate />
>                                                                     </telerikPrimitives:RadBorder>
>                                                                 </DataTemplate>
>                                                             </telerikDataControls:NonVirtualizedItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
>                                                         </telerikDataControls:NonVirtualizedItemsControl>
> ```

I hope this helps.. Thank you

Comment: please show the relevant code for what you have attempted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Xamarin.Forms MessagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center) , as the documentation mentioned ,the class implements the publish-subscribe pattern, allowing message-based communication between components that are inconvenient to link by object and type references .

#### Usage below

```
//in child view
MessagingCenter.Send<object, string>(this, "Hi", "John");    //parameter "John"

//in parent view 
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MainPage, string>(this, "Hi", async (sender, arg) =>
{
  //call the method
});
```